# Trigger Guava cache refresh when a table is updated

Tags: java, caching, guava

Presently am fectching the list of clients from db using `ClientDAO.getClients()` and caching using `guava` with 30 minutes refresh period as below

```
private List<String> getClients() {
        final Supplier<List<String>> supplier = () ->  ClientDAO.getClients();
        Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration(supplier, 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        return supplier.get();
    }
```

We have different application that updates `client` table and another application that reads from from the `client` table and caches as above and there is no `Restful` or any sort of api communication between these 2 applications. Is there any way to trigger this cache update whenever the corresponding `client` table in the database is updated instead of refreshing at specific time window 30 minutes?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Technically, it would probably be possible to notify the caching application through a database trigger, but this would only be working around the problem that these two applications don't communicate with each other.

Comment: am using SQL server 2008 r2 and yes these two application dont communicate with each other

Answer (score 0):

So from the question I will assume:

- there are two applications `A` and `B`
- there's a client table - let's call it `table X`
- `A` reads and caches data from `table X`
- `B` writes data to `table X`

`A` needs to know when `B` has written in `table X`, so that `A` can update it's cached data.

#### option 1

If you control `A` and `B`, you can extend the behavior - when `B` writes to the database and the write is successful, *`B` fires an event to `A`* (e.g. invokes a REST endpoint) and `A` will know to update its cache.

#### option 2

If you can't control `B`, but you can control `A` and the `DB`, you can use the `DB` as integration point - it's a common approach for legacy apps - the `DB` is the only place where the applications can integrate.

So again you can apply the same concept of *`B` fires an event to `A`*, but this time the event (initiated by a trigger) is stored in a table in the `DB` and the REST call is made from the DB itself using an internal procedure.

A straight forward approach would be:

- `B` writes data in `table X`
- there's an `insert trigger` for `table X`, which does a single INSERT statement into event storage table (let's call it `UPDATE_CACHE_EVENT`)

Your "update_cache_event" is now fired (e.g. saved in that table) and from this point on you have more options:

- `A` can monitor this table every second and trigger it's cache update when a new event is written
- `A` exposes REST API, which is invoked from the `DB` - e.g. in SQL server write a procedure, that monitors `UPDATE_CACHE_EVENT` table and calls `A`'s REST API.

#### option 3

[Debezium](https://debezium.io/)

Some thoughts:

- don't use a trigger itself to call the external API, use a dedicated procedure for that
- the trigger has performance penalty (e.g. each write to `table X` will invoke another insert to the event table), so you should consider this when designing your solution.